# Spring Cloud Data Flow s3 sink - 403 error > The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, amazon-iam

I've used spring cloud data flow starter s3 sink in a pipeline.
I think I've supplied all the required values. I'm getting this error:
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. **(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: XXXXXXXX)**

The values I supplied:

```
--cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=XXXXXXXX
--cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
--cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
--s3.acl=XXXXXXXXXX
--s3.bucket=XXXXXXXXXX
--s3.key-expression=headers.file_name
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or troubleshooting tip.

Thank You

Comment: Try fro here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218538/com-amazonaws-services-s3-model-amazons3exception-forbidden-service-amazon-s3

Comment: My error is specific to the signature calculation which is completely done by SCS s3 starter app. 
The error is as below:

'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.'

Comment: May you point where that  SCS s3 starter app does this signature calculation, please ?

Comment: I think the secret key had a '/' character which caused the signing not work well on s3 app. I regenerated access and secret key that don't have '/' character. That has fixed the issue

Comment: Artem...Here it is:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/

Comment: This is what has helped me resolve this:
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-you-provid/256395/6

Comment: Ok! Got to know, but again: where is that S3 app starter is guilty? Why it’s not a concern for the AWS S3 Client per se?

Answer (score 0):

The secret key had a '/' character which caused the signing does not work well on s3 starter sink app. 
I regenerated access and secret key that doesn't have '/' character. 
That has fixed the issue

Comment: Thanks for sharing the outcome. It sounds like you have had to do some customization to `s3-sink`. Could you contribute it back to the project?

Comment: Hi Sabby
My workaround was to regenerate an AWS security key that didn't have a '/'. I don't do any patching of s3-sink app. But, I'm willing to take a shot and try contributing a fix. Is there a place for a new contributor to get started?